# How to get any data from my real-time database in firebase using Go

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-realtime-database

I have simple test database with one row (key - value) and I can't get any data from database, although I use docs for Go (admin sdk - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start?authuser=0#go). I tried search but info how to use by Go is very small
[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/K68iToWsF0c) my code.
[Here](https://disk.yandex.tj/d/BNPcHJ09hl5oDw) my json-file.
In playground don't work, need use json-file and execute from code editor/IDE.

All I found was a couple of video tutorials from the firebase guys themselves where they show how to connect, but the same thing does not work for me. All other information is about how to use firebase via android, iphone and web (js).

```
package main

 import (
"context"
"fmt"
"log"

firebase "firebase.google.com/go"
"google.golang.org/api/option"
)

type Data struct {
TypeClient string `json:"typeClient,omitempty"`
}

var responseData structs.Data

func main() {
ctx := context.Background()

// Initialize the app with a custom auth variable, limiting the server's 
access
ao := map[string]interface{}{"uid": "my-service-worker"}
conf := &firebase.Config{
    DatabaseURL:  "https://test-v06f06-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    AuthOverride: &ao,
}

// Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("./test-v06f06-firebase-adminsdk-1ze0m- 
bbf3b57ef3.json")

app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, conf, opt)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Error initializing app:", err)
}
// fmt.Printf("%T\n", app)

client, err := app.Database(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Error initializing database client:", err)
}
// fmt.Printf("%T\n", client)

// The app only has access as defined in the Security Rules
ref := client.NewRef("/admin_permission")
// fmt.Printf("%T\n", ref)

// Get data
if err := ref.Get(ctx, &responseData); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Error reading from database:", err)
}
fmt.Println("Client Type -", responseData)}
```

In last row where print I get empty variable. The data is simply not written to the variable.
Help if you can. Thanks in advance.

[screenshot tiny db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buA1t.png)

Comment: Plz also post your code here and try and be a bit more specific about what "doesn't work" e.g. what logs are being output. Also note you shared a .json file which gives full access to your firebase so make sure to change your credentials soon.

Comment: I cant get data from my realtime database

Comment: For .json file yes I understand, its test db. As soon as the problem is solved, I will get rid of it.

Comment: Your code is trying to read from a path named `/admin_permission`. But based on your screenshot, you only have a `/typeClient` path in your database.

Comment: Yes you're right I should have specified the path, although the same firebase documentation for Go specifies a role with rights (// The app only has access as defined in the Security Rules
ref := client.NewRef("/some_resource")). After giving full access to my application the problem was solved. I must say firebase team should learn to make IT products like facebook, for example facebook offers a ready made test application when learning react.